# How to specify that outputs from database should output dates in a format excel recognizes

Tags: excel, specifications

This is more a question about how to write a specification for a vendor rather than a technical Query.
We have a couple of vendors that have custom excel spreadsheet outputs that they have prepared for us for reporting/data exchange etc.
I want to add some wording to a data dictionary to specify that any output for excel in date format should be fully compatible without users having to edit the cells in the spreadsheet (e.g. IF($A3="","",DATEVALUE(TEXT($A3,"dd/mm/yyyy")))

I have this so far:

*All Dates should be in DD/MM/YYYY format where a date exists, where no date exists the field should be blank.*
*All Dates output to excel format should be compatible with the excel format (i.e. should not require extra editing or formatting for excel to recognize them as dates.*

Comment: Use cell format. `TEXT()` function will output result as text string.

Comment: I know how to do the conversion in excel but what I need to know is how to write a specification for the vendor so I don't have to do conversion. It should also be database neutral

Comment: You should specify that the export should produce a DateTime serial value. If the export does that,  then you are not relying on Excel to cast a string  to a date (this is where it gets problematic) .  Any  display issues can be handled at the Excel end

Comment: Keep out: in Excel, serial values for dates start at January first, 1900. Make sure that, when serial values are used, that they start at the same date.